# Paypal attributes defined in local dtd now fails w3c validation

Tags: paypal, dtd

Since 2007, we have used a local DTD to add a tag-pair and to define several attributes for PayPlal and google++. This is the local DTD...

```
<!ELEMENT havindex EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST havindex id CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ENTITY % head.misc "(script|style|meta|link|object|isindex|havindex)*">
<!ENTITY % html.transitional PUBLIC
    "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- =========== 3 div attributes for googleplus share button ====== -->
<!ATTLIST div data-action       CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST div data-annotation   CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST div data-height       CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST div data-id           CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!-- =========== 2 script attributes for paypal support ========== -->
<!ATTLIST script data-pp-pubid          CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST script data-pp-placementtype  CDATA #IMPLIED>
%html.transitional;
```

... We recently converted the entire site to https (not sure that has anything to do with it, but just as an aside - checkout stuff was always htts, of course) and all of a sudden, it seems that the local DTD breaks the W3C validation - it fails immediately on the DTD. When I use a standard DTD, of course, the new tag and attributes are seen as validation errors. Any thoughts on how to use the local dtd or to define the attributes, at least?

The error is "500 Can't connect to www.WHATEVER-SITE.com:443" ... the site is https and on 443.

Anyway - TIA for any suggestions.

Comment: This looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48956393/407651

Comment: yes - this was my first attempt to post this question - THIS one may be deleted in favor of the second attempt.